# Non-element-wise vector division in Matlab returns a scalar! What is it?

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization, scalar

I spent over an hour chasing a bug in my code which was leading to a precision error. It turned out that in one of my equations, I had forgotten to divide two vectors element-wise; I had written `/` instead of `./`. Usually Matlab gives an error in these cases, e.g. if you try to multiply two vectors with `*` instead of `.*`. But in this case it's happily returning a scalar value! Is this supposed to happen, and does this value have any meaning?

For example,

```
x = 0 : 0.01 : 1;
y = x/exp(x);
```

sets `y=0.3132`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is supposed to happen. You used the [matrix right division operator `/`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html), and in this particular case it found a scalar value of `y` that solved the following system of equations in a least-squares sense:

```
y*exp(x) = x;
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems like very error-prone,  unfortunate syntax.

Comment: @MGA: It might seem that way, but it's very much intended. You just have to get used to the difference between [array and matrix operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html): dot notation for element-wise operations, no dot for linear algebra operations.